Visualizing the quotient space of a torus
I am trying to visualize the orbit space of the torus $T\backslash G$ ($T = S^1 \times S^1$) where $G$ is a set of homeomorphisms from $T$ to $T$, and the equivalence relation is given by $z_1 \sim z_2$ if and only if there exists a $g \in G$ such that $g(z_1) = z_2$.
For example, consider $G = \{ id, g \}$ where $id: T \rightarrow T$ and $g: T \rightarrow T$ is given by $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (-z_1, z_2)$. It seems like $T\backslash G$ is homeomorphic to the Klein Bottle, but I am having trouble visualizing so. Here is what I have, which is a rather standard quotient construction:
I know that the torus can be obtained as the quotient of this unit square, by identifying the red edges with each other (wrapping around to form a cylinder), and then the blue edges with each other (wrapping around to form a torus).

Moreover, from the unit square, we can show that the torus is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle via the following series of transformations: 1) Firstly, we cut along the vertical middle of the square, 2) which gives rise to two separate polygonal regions. 3) Now, we will flip the left rectangle vertically and glue the left rectangle to the right rectangle along the bottom red edge. 4) Removing the middle red edge (that was already glued), and recoloring the green->blue edge as purple, we get the final diagram. In the final diagram, we can again glue the top red edge with the bottom red edge, as well as the two purple edges with each other, to obtain the Klein Bottle.

However, I am having trouble seeing how this transformation relates at all to the $G$-action. Intuitively, my guess is that the left section (or right section) comprising of the red and blue edges of the square will correspond to the fundamental domain for the $G$-action on the torus. Hence, performing the quotient construction requires us to identify red (resp. blue) edges in the right section with those in the left section. So, we will need to glue the right rectangle with this left section as illustrated. How do we make this correspondence precise?

The torus is not homeomorphic to the Klein bottle! You've glued the front of the red arrow to the back of the red arrow and flipped the direction of gluing along the blue and green edges.

To address your original problem, first consider the simpler case $S^1/g$ with $g(z)=-z$. Each point of the circle is identified with its opposite point...

Thanks @Karl! I think that helps a lot pictorially - we end up with a semicircle (upper half of the unit circle) in the case of $S^1 \backslash {g, id }$.

Using the $g$ you describe, the quotient $T \setminus G$ is homeomorphic to the torus, not the Klein bottle. One way to prove this is to use the function
$$f : T^2 \to T^2 \qquad f(z_1,z_2) = (z_1^2,z_2)
$$
This function is a quotient map (in fact it is a degree 2 self-covering map). Furthermore, the set of point pre-images of $f$ is identical to the set of orbits of the action of your group $G$ on $T^2$, namely all two point sets of the form $\{(z_1,z_2),(-z_1,z_2)\}$. By the universal property of quotient maps, it follows that $f$ induces a homeomorphism between its codomain, namely $T^2$, and the orbit space $T \setminus G$. (In fact $f$ is a normal covering map and $G$ is its group of deck transformations).

Thanks! Is it right to assume that the point $(s, t)$ in the unit square corresponds to the point $(e^{2\pi i s}, e^{2\pi i t})$ in the torus (viewed as a subspace of the complex plane)? In that case, the map that you have provided corresponds to the transformation $(s, t) \mapsto (2s, t)$ on the complex plane, pictorially "cutting" up the unit square and leaving us with the "left" piece. Then, we can proceed with the construction as in the question to get the Klein bottle.

I'm not quite sure what you mean about your Klein bottle comment, but if you are careful enough you can find a different order 2 cyclic group $G$ and generator $g \in G$ (not the one in your post) such that the quotient is a Klein bottle. But that's a different question than what you posted here.

I have a little trouble seeing how the $G$-orbit in the map $f$ are 2 point sets of the form ${ (z_1, z_2), (-z_1, z_2) }$. By following the definition of the orbit equivalence, $f(z_1, z_2) =(-z_1, z_2)$ may not be true.

Sorry about the first comment - I had misunderstood that the map you provided gave rise to the Klein bottle via the orbit space. Another map that I thought of such that the quotient is a Klein bottle is $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (z_1, \bar z_2)$.

The orbit space for the order 2 cyclic group $G$ generated by $g(z_1,z_2)=(z_1,\bar z_2)$ is the annulus, not the Klein bottle.
